# how to insert static values into table variable using select statement

Tags: sql-server

How to insert static values in table variable using select statement (without using multiple insert statment) in MS SQL Server.

e.g

```
Declare @xyz table(
abc varchar(10),
pqr varchar(10)
)
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) values('a1', 'p1')
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) values('a2', 'p2')
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) values('a3', 'p3')
```

Instead, Is there a way to write something like below ?

```
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr)
select abc, pqr
from (
    'a1', 'p1',
    'a2', 'p2',
    'a3', 'p3'
)res
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr)
select abc, pqr
from (VALUES
    ('a1', 'p1'),
    ('a2', 'p2'),
    ('a3', 'p3')
)res(abc, pqr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) values('a1', 'p1'),('a2', 'p2'),('a3', 'p3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to repeat the insert statement...

```
Declare @xyz table(
abc varchar(10),
pqr varchar(10)
)
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) 
values

('a1', 'p1')
,('a2', 'p2')
,('a3', 'p3')
```

Or you can nest it with `union all`

```
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) 
select abc, pqr
from
(
    select
    'a1' as abc , 'p1' as pqr
    union all
    select
    'a2', 'p2'
    union all
    select
    'a3', 'p3'
) x
```

Or a table constructor

```
insert into @xyz(abc, pqr) 
select abc, pqr
from
(values('a1','p1'),('a2', 'p2'),('a3', 'p3'))  as x(abc, pqr)
```